# Make payable App free for only one country (Google Console)

Tags: android, google-play-console

Not sure I am allowed to ask this here, but I guess this has also to do with developing apps.

Is there a way to give a payable app for free for only one country?
Meaning that I have a payed app and I would like to give the app for free in a specific country.

Comment: i doubt it, doesn't seem like a normal or very fair use-case from the store's point of view, i imagine people would be quite annoyed if they knew they were paying for something that is free in another country, but perhaps it actually is possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, an app is either paid or free regardless of country.
For paid apps, prices can be set per country but this is always higher than 0.00

Minimum prices
https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/10532353?visit_id=637826106815754209-1478538205&rd=1

Set up your app's prices:
https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6334373?hl=en

Comment: I feared this answer. So we have to setup a free new app (packagename) with same codebase in google play console to be avaiable for free for specific country and only allow this country, right?

Comment: Yes, I'm afraid so..